# Attempting to install Magento Mage_GoogleShopping extension

Tags: magento

But all I get from my Connect Manager is the following message:

```
community/Mage_GoogleShopping: Version for 'Mage_GoogleShopping' was not detected
```

If I try and use the version 1 extension key all I get is:

```
Couldn't resolve host 'magento-core'
```

I am using a mostly fresh install of Magento Community 1.5.0.1  (I say mostly because we do have our own template but it is very basic).

Anyone have any luck installing this extension.  GoogleShopping is a huge boon to our hit count and the recent changes to the google products API has really affected our implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this extension is still in alpha stability, you need to change your preference settings ("settings" tab in your magento connect manager) for "preferred state"

Comment: +1 for effort, though as I said below I never got to try it as I fixed a different way.

Comment: @lazyDBA, I don't think this is really a different way, you just installed a newer version of magentoconnect which solve this bug, ie, express better the fact that the problem is your preferred state setting

Comment: I didn't realize I had upgraded the down-loader.  But I have verified that you are correct.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OSdave had the right answer ... but the way I fixed the error message was I blew away the download folder on the server and re-copied over from the original Magento install package.

Once I had done that I re-ran the Extension Key in Connect and this time it actually said.  "That Extension is in Alpha stage.  You'll need to change your preferences to install it."

I did NOT get the error above anymore.  At that point everything worked like a charm.